# Check contents of multi-dimensional array against a single array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to check if all the elements of an array(arr1,arr2,arr3...) in a multi-dimensional array(arrs) match the ones of a given array(randomArr) that can be of any length. This is what I came up with so far:

```
  var randomArr = ['1','4','3'];

  function check(arrA,arrB){
    for(i=0;i<arrA.length;i++){
      if(arrB.indexOf(arrA[i])==-1){return false;}
    }
    return true;
  }

  function superCheck(){
    var arr1 = ['1','2','3']
    ,  arr2 = ['4','5','6']
    ,  arr3 = ['7','8','9']
    ,  arr4 = ['1','4','7']
    ,  arr5 = ['2','5','8']
    ,  arr6 = ['3','6','9']
    ,  arr7 = ['1','5','9']
    ,  arr8 = ['3','5','7'];
    var arrs = [arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4, arr5, arr6, arr7, arr8];

    for(i=0;i<arrs.length;i++){
      if(check(arrs[i],randomArr)){return true;}
    }
    return false;
  }

  console.log(superCheck());
```

But when I try to run it I get this error(An infinite loop (or a loop taking too long) was detected, so we stopped its execution.). How can I make this work??

Comment: You have a typo in `if (arr2.indefOf(arr1[i])`, it should be `if (arr2.indexOf(arr1[i])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to check if avery element of a single array is inside another array. This is the solution:

```
function check(superset,subset){
  return subset.every(function(val){
    return (superset.indexOf(val)>=0);
  })
}
```

Here, you'll check if all the values inside subset are present in the superset. If one of the items in the subset were not to be present, it's index would be -1 and therefore the function would return false.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
var winning = [win1, win2, win3, win4, win5, win6, win7, win8],
    xScore = 0,
    oScore = 0,
    scored = false,
    xMarkedStr = xMarked.sort().join(''),
    oMarkedStr = oMarked.sort().join('');

winning.some(win => {
   var winStr = win.join('');
   if (xMarkedStr === winStr) {
       xScore++;
       scored = true;
   }
   if (oMarkedStr === winStr) {
       oScore++;
       scored = true;
   }
   return scored;
});

console.log(xScore, oScore);
```